# Know when my function is over

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

This is my functions

```
function parseLinks(links, callback) {

    var products = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        request(links[i], function (error, response, body) {
            var product;
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);

                // title
                var title = $('h1').text();
                if (!title)
                    var title = $('title').text();

                var description = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');

                product = new Product(links[0].trim(), title.trim(), description.trim());
                products.push(product);
            }
        });
    }
    callback(products) // the callback only do a console.log(products)
}
```

After that, I want to do a **console.log(products)** who display all the products.
So I setup a callback attached to parseLinks and call it after the for loop. The problem is in my for loop, I call asynchronous function **request** each times, so my callback is called before the end of all the **request** calls, so my **console.log(products)** print an empty array.

Do you know how fix that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if all the asynchronous calls have finished. Create an inner function that calls `callback` when all asynchronous work is done:

```
function parseLinks(links, callback) {
    var products = [],
        numberOfItems = links.length; // numbers of linkes to be parsed

    function checkIfDone() {          // this function will be called each time link is parsed
        numberOfItems--;              // decrement the numberOfItems (number that tells us how many links left)
        if(numberOfItems === 0)       // if there are none left (all links are parsed), then call callback with the resultant array.
            callback(products);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        request(links[i], function (error, response, body) {
            // ...

            checkIfDone();            // everytime a link is parsed, call checkIfDone
        });
    }
}
```

You can embed the logic of `checkIfDone` inside the function `request` directly. I used a separate function for clarity.

Comment: Thank you ! And can you explain me ? There is a special order for the asynchronous call in the stack (are they executed in order or not) ?

Comment: @Tech The `for` launch all the asynchronous calls at once. The order of their finish is arbitrary (depends on how it takes a link to finish).

Comment: @Tech If you want to keep the order, you'll have to chain the calls (call one when the other has finished), or use `i` instead of `push` to map each product to the index of the link in the `links` array.

Comment: but there is a counter (i) in my for. So the order of finish is arbitrary  but not the order of launching ?

Comment: @Tech The order you call `request` is ight. But request doesn't do it job right away, it's just register a function that will be called when the job is done. `for` won't take much time to call `request` on all links (so you can regard it as launching all asynch calls at once).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async).

```
var async = require("async");

function parseLinks(links, callback) {

    var products = [];
    async.forEach(links, function(link, done) {
        request(link, function (error, response, body) {
            var product;
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);

                // title
                var title = $('h1').text();
                if (!title)
                    var title = $('title').text();

                var description = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');

                product = new Product(links[0].trim(), title.trim(), description.trim());
                products.push(product);
            }

            done();
        });
    }, function() {
        callback(products);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Can you explain how works async ? Like a synchronizer ?

Comment: @Tech `async.forEach` takes an array as its first argument (`links`) and a callback as its second argument. The callback is run once for each item in the array, then runs the function `done` it receives as its second argument when it's done. After `done` is called for every item, `async.forEach`'s third argument is run, which is your final callback. [Here's the documentation](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async.each](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) from [asnyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module

Simplified code:

```
function parseLinks(links, callback) {
    var products = [];

    async.each(links, function(link, requestCallback) {
        request(links[i], function(error, response, body) {
            //... rest of your code
            requestCallback(); //Request has ended
        });


    }, function(err) {
        //All requests ended!
        callback();
    });
}
```